# move_uploaded_file not working in localhost

Tags: php, file-upload

I can not upload the file to the server `xampp`

Code in PHP:

```
$nome = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$tipo = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];
$dimensione = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
$tmp = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
$url_destinazione = "http://localhost/PHP/Giornale/" . $nome;
$r = move_uploaded_file($tmp, $url_destinazione);
```

Result html page

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(http://localhost/PHP/Giornale/nnnnn.png): failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\Giornale\inserisci_articolo.php on line 117

Comment: don't use a url. RTM http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php use a path.

Comment: ^ your `$url_destinazione` variable should be a local path on your server - not a url. If you could just use URLs like this I could use `move_uploaded_file($tmp, 'https://www.facebook.com/index.php')`. Consider what dangerous situations that could lead to.

Comment: @h2ooooooo Yeah, probably even more cat photos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`move_uploaded_file()` does not take a url on the website. It takes a path to a location on the filesystem.

So you'd have to use something like this:

```
$nome = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$tipo = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];
$dimensione = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
$tmp = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];

$destinazion e= "/location/of/the/folder/PHP/Giornale/".$nome;
$r = move_uploaded_file($tmp, $destinazione);
```

The [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) has a good section on file uploads.